# Russian fluency

Tags: discussion

I hope I found the right section to talk a bit off-topic.

Last Saturday (10/02) I've been to a coffee bar attended by many people of different nationalities.

I got to talk to a Russian lady in her 30s, and after leaving the coffee bar, we walked around the town for some more time, until we split up.

I spoke to her almost always in Russian, for a few hours. Just told a few English words to talk about food and cooking, the kind of vocabulary I didn't bother learn in Russian so far.

Well, my Russian turned out better than what I would expect. The last time I had actually spoken in Russian face to face was during my short trip to Russia last June. Back then I had to speak mainly in English, and whenever I tried to speak in Russian, I had to take a break at every word pronounced.

So, how is it possible that, after not talking in Russian for eight months, I've managed to suddenly get enough fluency to keep a conversation in Russian for a few hours, without ever stuttering?

If this question is unrelated to anything on this forum anyway, feel free to remove my informal question.

Comment: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/

Comment: please use chat room for this kind of discussions.

Answer (score 0):

What? xD You can't completely forget a language. In fact, you just get rusty at it over time and it becomes your 'passive' skill.
If the Russian lady speaks only English for a quite long time, she will get rusty at Russian.